# Запрос к API VK

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, инспекция-кода

```
//Запрос к VK, токен уже есть в переменной $tok
$wall = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=".implode(',', $users)."&v=5.40&access_token=$tok");
$wall = json_decode($wall);
$result = $wall->response;
print_r($result);
```

Вот есть у меня такой запрос, но я слышал, что он плохой. Подскажите чем он плох, и если можно. напишите нормальный запрос.

Comment: Ничем не плох. Запрос как запрос.

Comment: Если много раз жму f5, то запрос не проходит) И потом в скрипте у меня ошибка нехорошая из-за этого запроса. А бывает и само по себе с первого раза запрос возвращает пустоту. Потом скрипт продолжает выполняться с пустотой, а должны айди обрабатываться. Там в $users их не много, 10 - 30 штук, не более. Вообще дело идёт так: я беру 20 uidvk например из базы, прогоняю в их в запросе, потомполучаю массив, далее вырезаю из массива забаненных в вк. и потом уже работаю с теми юзерами, что остались, с теми, кто не забанен.

Comment: ну так естественно, API ВКонтакте устанавливает свои ограничения на запросы.

Comment: Какие ограничения то? 30 айди? Там всё нормально работает, просто иногда запрос не возращает ничего. А если много раз быстро обновить страницу, то точно ничего не вернёт с последнего раза.

Comment: Ограничение на частоту запросов. Чтобы отследить ошибку, замените `$wall = json_decode($wall);`на `$wall = json_decode($wall); print_r($wall);`

Comment: Ограничение на частоту окей. но бывает иногда, что с первого захода не срабатывает -_-

Comment: Отследите конкретно, что отдаёт ВК. Выше написал.

Comment: Всё правильно. [ error_msg ] = > Слишком много запросов в секунду. Тогда так понимаю надо просто взять, и в случае этой ошибки (а лучше в случае пустого $result) условие создать на завершение работы и редирект. Ок. но сам запрос. он совершенно нормален и никак не уязвим. юзать его можно?

Comment: Да, если есть ошибка, то выполняйте свои условия. Запрос никак не уязвим, это ведь стандартный и единственный api-метод ВК. Чтобы ограничения так часто не касались Вас, можно например получить `access_token` с мобильного приложения, там частота запросов совершенно другая или с разных аккаунтов разные `access_token` рандомно передавать. Ознакомьтесь в самом низу с частотой запросов к API — https://vk.com/dev/api_requests

Comment: @PHPcoder заканчивайте использовать file_get_contents.

Answer (score 1):

Запрос норм. Надо смотреть в контексте приложения. Если часто могут обновлять страницу – стоит кэшировать запрос, чтобы не бомбить ВК слишком часто.

Если требуется выполнить много запросов подряд, можно запоминать время выполнения последних трёх, и перед очередным запросом проверять, прошло ли уже 1000 миллисекунд со времени самого старого из них. Если нет – поспать чуток: [`usleep()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usleep.php).

Comment: Так-то хватит и 333 миллисекунд, в вк ведь ограничения на 3 запроса в секунду

Comment: Если запросов немного. Когда важна эффективность на сотнях запросов, лучше не полениться и посчитать время последних трёх.